# Linux join column files of different lengths

Tags: text

I've seen a lot of similar questions to this but I haven't found an answer. I have several text files, each with two columns, but the columns in each file are different lengths, e.g.

```
file1:
type val
1    2
2    4
3    2

file2:
type val
1    9
2    8
3    9
4    7

I want:
type val type val
1    2   1    9
2    4   2    8
3    2   3    9
         4    7
```

'join' gives something like this:

```
type val type val
1    2   1    9
2    4   2    8
3    2   3    9
     4   7
```

I could write a script but I'm wondering if there is a simple command.
Thanks,

Comment: Ok, couldn't wait for an answer, so wrote a python script. Here it is in case its useful to anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, couldn't wait for an answer, so wrote a python script. Here it is in case its useful to anyone.

```
import sys
import os
#joins all the tab delimited column files in a folder into one file with multiple columns
#usage joincolfiles.py /folder_with_files outputfile
folder = sys.argv[1] #working folder, put all the files to be joined in here
outfile=sys.argv[2] #output file
cols=int(sys.argv[3]) #number of columns, only works if each file has same number
g=open(outfile,'w')
a=[]
b=[]
c=0
for files in os.listdir(folder):
    f=open(folder+"/"+files,'r')
    b=[]
    c=c+1
    t=0
    for line in f:
        t=t+1
        if t==1:
            b.append(str(files)+line.rstrip('\n'))
        else:
            b.append(line.rstrip('\n')) #list of lines
    a.append(b) #list of list of lines
    f.close()
print "num files", len(a)       
x=[] 
for i in a:
    x.append(len(i))
maxl = max(x) #max length of files
print 'max len',maxl
for k in range(0,maxl): #row number
    for j in a:
        if k<len(j):
            g.write(j[k]+"\t")
        else:
            g.write("\t"*cols)
    g.write("\n")
g.close()
```